# How to sync an invitation on Iphone to Google Calendar

Tags: ios, google-calendar

I have sync setup between my Google Calendar and my Iphone5 calendar.  This works perfectly in both directions.

Yesterday my squash buddy created an event in his own (Iphone) calendar and invited me.  I accepted this and it now shops up in my own (Iphone) calendar.

However, it doesn't seem to sync to Google Calendar. This is probably caused by the fact that it is somehow still 'his' event and not mine?

Is there any way to get this event to also sync to my Google Calendar?

Comment: To what email address was his invite sent? Was it your Apple ID/iCloud email or your Gmail?

Comment: To my AppleId email, which is coincedentally also my Gmail

Comment: Did you add the event to a calendar that is actually synced with Google or maybe (by accident) to a local calendar only?

Comment: The event got into my Iphone calendar, because I was invited by my squash buddy, so I'm not the 'owner' of the event - which is probably the reason why it doesn't sync, but I want to make sure.

Comment: If the iPhone calendar syncs to Gmail this event should be synced nonetheless.

Comment: Even events that are not my own? I want to believe you, but it really doesn't...